# Is there a download manager like Tucan in KDE?

Tags: linux, kde, download-manager

[Tucan Manager](http://tucaneando.com/index.html) is a free file sharing application designed for 1-Click Hosters like Rapidshare or Megaupload. It has captcha resolution, interchangeable links, premium user accounts, and many other great features.

Is there something similar for KDE?

Answer (score 3):

[JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/) would fit the bill.

Comment: how to install and use it?

Comment: i'm using jdownloader too, but i would love to find out there is an alternative for kde users. java is just way too heavy.

Answer (score 1):

**Megaupload Starter plugin for Konqueror:**

http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/Megaupload+Starter?content=121287

**Rapidshare Starter plugin for Konqueror:**

http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/Rapidshare+Starter?content=121292